# How to find a String of last 2 items in colon separated string

Tags: java, java-8

I have a string = `ab:cd:ef:gh`. On this input, I want to return the string  `ef:gh` (third colon intact).
The string `apple:orange:cat:dog` should return `cat:dog` (there's always 4 items and 3 colons).

I could have a loop that counts colons and makes a string of characters after the second colon, but I was wondering if there exists some easier way to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the split() method for your string.

```
String example = "ab:cd:ef:gh";
String[] parts = example.split(":");
System.out.println(parts[parts.length-2] + ":" + parts[parts.length-1]);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using this as we are appending the delimiter manually

Answer (score 1):

```
String example = "ab:cd:ef:gh";
String[] parts = example.split(":",3); // create at most 3 Array entries
System.out.println(parts[2]);
```

Comment: Good way of doing but it won't work dynamically, if my string contains more delimiters it fails

Comment: If you would like a more generic solution I'd expect you to ask for it.

Comment: I know the answer and it was given below, we all come here and search for generic solutions to make our life easier. So I suggested to try for that. I really like your approach

Answer (score 0):

The [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function might be what you're looking for here. Use the colon, like in the documentation as your delimiter. You can then obtain the last two indexes, like in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is easier way.
First, is by using method split from String class:

```
 String txt= "ab:cd:ef:gh";
 String[] arr = example.split(":");
 System.out.println(arr[arr.length-2] + " " + arr[arr.length-1]);
```

and the second, is to use [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class.

Comment: This wouldn't work if there was more than 4 elements in the array(or less), the numbers 2 and 3 should be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Use overloaded version of [lastIndexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-int-), which takes the starting index as 2nd parameter:

```
  str.substring(a.lastIndexOf(":", a.lastIndexOf(":") - 1) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to match your input, something like `[^:]+:[^:]+$`. Using a pattern would probably be easier to maintain as you can easily change it to handle for example other separators, without changing the rest of the method.

Using a pattern is also likely be more efficient than `String.split()` as the latter is also converting its parameter to a `Pattern` internally, but it does more than what you actually need.

This would give something like this:

```
String example = "ab:cd:ef:gh";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^:]+:[^:]+$");
final Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(example);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // extract the matching group, which is what we are looking for
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // prints ef:gh
} else {
    // handle invalid input
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```

Note that you would typically extract `regex` as a reusable constant to avoid compiling the pattern every time. Using a constant would also make the pattern easier to change without looking at the actual code.